# Specific 301 redirect from domain1 to domain2 on wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a WP network installation. And I want to migration blog1 on domain1.com to blog2 on domain2.com. 
Nothing hard here but when it came to migrate

- domain1.com/articles/YYYY/ to domain2.com/YYYY
- (or domain1.com/articles/YYYY/MM/ to domain2.com/YYYY/MM/)
- and domain1.com/articles/YYYY/MM/DD/my-article-title to domain2.com/my-article-title,

I mess with RewriteCond and RewriteRules...

How can I achieve it ?

This is my .htaccess on the WP Network

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0

# Full redirect from domain1 to domain2
# it works if uncommented but it's not exactly what i want
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thanks for your time.

Note : blog1 and blog2 installations are OK, similar databases, articles working on both side. Problem is only on 301.

Answer (score 0):

This should change `domain1.com/articles/YYYY/` to `domain2.com/YYYY` or `domain1.com/articles/YYYY/MM/` to `domain2.com/YYYY/MM/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:
To redirect to `http://www.domain2.com/arctives/YYY/MM/DD`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^articles/(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/articles/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not resolve :
`domain1.com/articles/YYYY/MM/DD/my-article-title to domain2.com/my-article-title`

it's doing `domain1.com/articles/YYYY/MM/DD/my-article-title to domain2.com/YYYY/MM/DD/my-article-title`

Comment: You didn't ask for that though, you wanted `domain1.com/articles/YYYY/ to domain2.com/YYYY`